# WebChromeClient.onReceivedIcon's icon get recycled sometime later in Android 4.4+

Tags: bitmap, webchromeclient

public void onReceivedIcon (WebView view, Bitmap icon)

in my code, when this callback get called i keep a ref of icon, will keep it around for a long time. I need this to show as history item's icon, it works well in all version of Android except Android 4.4+, in 4.4 i get some crash like this:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@65189840

so my question is, does Android 4.4 automatically recycle the icon this method received? Android doc say nothing about this, also seems in earlier version it didn't do that job. Anyone knows about this? 
i only find the call begins at chromium/src/android_webview/native/aw_contents.cc#onReceivedIcon(const GURL& icon_url, const SkBitmap& bitmap) function, but where does this method called and where's recycle of the SkBitmap happens???

some related code in chromium is preferred, thanks in advance.

Comment: Happens to me in a Webview when I try to login to google account in YouTube. Also on 4.4.